# JpaRepository method name with DISTINCT ON

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I'm creating Spring application and I'm using JpaRepository to simplify database queries.

I have problem with creating method name using JpaRepository conventions with DISTINCT ON. Here's my SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (s.device_id)
  s.status_id,
  s.error,
  s.receive_time,
  s.device_id
FROM statuses s
ORDER BY s.device_id, s.receive_time DESC
```

I tried such name but it's not working:

```
List<Status> findDistinctByDeviceId_OrderByReceiveTimeDesc();
```

Here's my classes (simplified):

```
public class Status {
    private long status_id;
    private String error;
    private Date receive_time;
    private Device device_id;
}

public class Device {
    private long device_id;
    private String name;
}
```

Is is even possible to use DISTINCT ON in method name? I wouldn't like to use SQL queries because my classes are much more complex than above and I would like to add every field to query.

Comment: Well for starters you don't have a field named `device`... You have a field named `device_id`.

Comment: @M.Deinum it's just error in post here, in code it was ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used something like this and it works:

```
@Query(value = "select distinct on (s.device_id) s.* " +
        "from statuses s " +
        "order by s.device_id, s.receive_time desc",
        nativeQuery = true)
public List<Status> getStatuses();
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to use @NativeNamedQuery to achiev the result

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, **DISTINCT ON** is database specific, than a global SQL command. And it looks like distinct just for one column.

But if you want to DISTINCT the whole SQL line, you could do something like:

```
// Spring Data allows you to specify the entity you want to distinct after the word "Distinct"
List<Status> findDistinctStatusByOrderByReceiveTimeDesc();

// Or before the word "Distinct"
List<Status> findStatusDistinctByOrderByReceiveTimeDesc();
```

This would already ensure that you'll not receive any duplicated lines, creating a SQL output like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  s.device_id,
  s.status_id,
  s.error,
  s.receive_time,
  s.device_id
FROM statuses s
ORDER BY s.device_id, s.receive_time DESC
```

More information on this, you can check into [Spring Data Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation)